# jQuery Cycle Plugin with typewriter transition effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, effects, cycle, transition

Wondering if anyone knows how to achieve a typewriter effect with the jQuery Cycle plugin.

See here for desired effect: http://www.hungry-media.com/code/jQuery/tickerType/

Thanks.
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Cycle's `after` and `before` transition callbacks to invoke other plugins on the element being displayed. You'll need to use a plugin dedicated only to the type effect, like [Effects jTypeWriter](http://www.dummwiam.com/jTypeWriter) to invoke the effect when an element is displayed.

```
$("#cycle-pane").cycle({
  before: function() { $(this).jTypeWriter(); }
});

<div id="cycle-pane">
  <div>First text</div>
  <div>Second text</div>
</div>
```

You'll need to keep an eye on the timing of Cycle transitions and the duration of the type effect and also any cleanup or reset that may need to be done if Cycle is running on a loop.

Comment: That's fantastic. Exactly what I wanted. Thankyou. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the plugin you referenced? Doesn't look like the Cycle plugin was built for type-writer effects.

Comment: I'm using some of the advanced pager functionality of the cycle plugin, and various other things that the cycle plugin can handle which others I find cannot.

Plus I think if we can get the typewriter effect working then it would be a nice addition for Mike to add in to the plugin for others to use.